# Program never executes '0' in my string array of char

Tags: c

I am trying to make a simple program that can reverse a string

```
#include "pch.h"
#define MAX 6

int main()
{

    puts("Hello and welcome. I will now reverse the word 'Hello' for you.");
    
    char const ord[MAX] = { "Hello" };


    for (size_t i = MAX; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        printf_s("%c", ord[i]);
    }

    
}
```

[image]

However, I end up with only "ello" and some weird character like square shows up on my terminal. I tried and debug, and I think it is because the program never executes "0", so I also tried to make  'i >= 0" in my for loop, but that just leads to a critical failures and the whole program stops. Any idea what to do from here?

Comment: Try setting `i` to the number of characters in the string `- 1`. Also using a `size_t` is always going to be >= 0 since it is unsigned. (So either use a signed variable type or check if it `!= -1` since unsigned integer underflow is defined.

Comment: Don't guess. Work out the math and logic on paper. Make sure you're accessing valid indexes of the array.

Comment: Regardless of that, MAX is 9 but the string is only 5 chars...

Comment: You just edited your question by changing the value of `MAX` from 9 to 6. This is very confusing, as this appeared to be one of the things that caused the problem. Is the problem solved now? Please don't edit your question by silently including the solution in it. The question is the question; the solution should be in the answers.

Comment: @ColonD That is funny, because when I do make 'i >=0 && i != -1' then it prints the whole thing out reverse but it still prints like a weird square like figure that I have no clue where it comes from?

Comment: The weird square is you accessing element at index 6 of the array, which is out of bounds (index 5 is the highest in an array of length 6). This is just reading some random memory location which just so happens to be the character of the weird square.

Comment: @stef I don't really understand you? I changed MAX from 9 to 6 because another in the comments pointed that out. In Denmark, "hello" is 9 letters and not 6, so I just translated the code quick, so you guys had a more easy way of understanding it. Please feel free to ask if there is something about my question that confuses you.

Comment: @ColonD I thought you were supposed to have an index of "your word"+1, since there is a so called "\0" that the terminal needs to execute?

Comment: So let's say you have the string, { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }, this is 6 characters long ("Hello" and a null character terminator for the end of the string). 'H' is index 0, '\0' is index 5. Index 6 is ???.

Comment: @ColonD I can't have my "MAX" be 5, then it says my array is out of bounds. Making it 6 or "your string"  +1 makes the program work.

Comment: Having MAX be 6 is fine, as long as you do `i = MAX - 1` in the for loop - since the last index of the array is 5.

Comment: What happens if you do `"Hello"` instead of `{"Hello"}`?

Comment: @ColonD Exactly, but I get this error when making it 5... "A value of type "const char [6]" cannot be used to initialize an entity  of type "const char [5]""

Comment: the problem with changing 9 to 6 is that now your question is inconsistent. You will not get the output you report with `MAX == 6`, so there is no point in asking why the code outputs that output. It doesn't.

Comment: That is correct, the "Hello\0" is 6 characters long, and you cannot use it to initialise a array of 5 characters. Glad I could help.

Comment: @ColonD 2 quick questions.

1. How do I upvote comments?

2. How do I flag my question as answered/ completed?

Comment: I believe upvoting is something you have to unlock by contributing but it does not take too much time to unlock it, but do not worry about it. I will post my comment as an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Comment: You cannot "flag" your question as answered because there's no acutal answer. Otherwise you could have accepted it, marking it with a green tick. Comments are just for questions, unstructured suggestions or partial answers.

Comment: @user253751 It works also with ColonD's solution!

Comment: @RobertoCaboni And how do I do that? I am fairly new to StackOverflow.

Comment: If someone answers (and nobody dit it so far) you'll see an "empty" grey tick near the upper left corner of the answer. Selecting it will change it into green and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @NemanjaVuksanovic You have asked a question about a problem in your code. Some users gave you a few suggestions in comments, which is good. But then you edited your question by modifying your code in the question to try and fix the code. Then, the question about the problem in your code no longer makes sense because you changed the code. Please don't edit your question like that. Fix the code on your program, but don't fix the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program first creates an array:

```cpp
char const ord[MAX] = { "Hello" };
```

The array is represented in memory as 6 characters:
`'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'`

The indexes of these characters are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.

When you start your for loop, you need to start at index `MAX - 1`, index `5`, because index `6` is not part of the array.

Another thing is that `size_t` is an unsigned type, meaning it can not go below 0. Because of this, `i >= 0` will always be true so the loop will never end. You can use `i != -1` because unsigned integer underflow is defined.

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```c
#define MAX 9

int main()
{
    char const ord[MAX] = "Hello";
}
```

You are reserving a memory area of size `MAX`, and writing the 6 characters `'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'` to the first 6 cells of this area. Since `MAX == 9 == 6+3`, there are 3 remaining uninitialized cells. The 3 remaining cells are uninitialized and might contain anything; in C, trying to read the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour.

In most cases, the actual behaviour is that the 3 uninitialized cells will contain garbage, *i.e.*, arbitrary values. So the array `ord` in memory looks something like:

```
{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', X, Y, Z}
```

where X, Y and Z can be anything. If you try to print these values as characters, you might get something a bit ugly, since not all values translate to a printable ascii character.

One quick fix would be to write `#define MAX 6` instead of `#define MAX 9`. In my opinion, this would be a bad fix. There are two different numbers here: the number of memory cells you reserve in your char array, and the actual length of the string. You should keep these two numbers clearly separate as they represent two different concepts, and your code shouldn't rely on the actual length of the string being exactly `MAX`. In fact, to avoid the string accidentally becoming larger than `MAX`, you could give yourself some latitude and write `#define MAX 100` so you're certain that `MAX` is larger than the length of the string. Note that `MAX` is a **constant**. For the actual length of the string, you should have a **variable**, not a constant.

You can find out the length of a string using function `strlen` from header `string.h`, or by writing your own `my_strlen`.

**Last issue:** `size_t` is an unsigned type, meaning variables can never take a negative value. When a value of an unsigned type reaches 0 and you try decrementing it with `i--`, it "wraps around" and takes the largest possible positive value. For this reason, the loop `for (size_t i = MAX; i >= 0; --i)` cannot work properly: the condition will always be true and the loop will never stop. In addition, when `i` wraps around to a super large value, trying to access `ord[i]` is undefined behaviour and most likely will crash your program. Normally, your compiler should give you a warning for such an infinite loop. If it doesn't, try compiling with flags `-Wall -Wextra`.

```c
#include <stddef.h>   // size_t
#include <stdio.h>    // printf

#define MAX 100

size_t my_strlen(char const *str);
void reverse(char *dest, char const *source, size_t len);

int main()
{
    char const ord[MAX] = "Hello";
    char reversed[MAX];
    size_t length; 
    size_t i;

    length = my_strlen(ord);

    printf("Hello and welcome. I will now reverse the word '%s' for you.\n", ord);

    reverse(reversed, ord, length);

    printf("Reversed word: '%s'.\n", reversed)

    return 0;
}

size_t my_strlen(char const *str)
{
    size_t len;
    for (len = 0; str[len] != '\0'; ++len)
    {
    }
    return len;
}

void reverse(char *dest, char const *source, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        dest[i] = source[len - i];
    }
    dest[len] = '\0';
}
```